# Why does df_sub not recognize dates as part of the index?

Tags: python, pandas

I am running into a key error:"Transaction Date not in Index"- when attempting to select the column 'Transaction Date' from df_sub. What do I need to do to the function to enable it to recognize 'Transaction Date' in the index? 
I have tried to_datetime and set_index, however without fruitful results. Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df=pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\samantha.ettinger\\Documents\\Status Import Attempt 11.19.2019.xlsx")

print(df)

df_sub = df[['Transaction Date','Utility Account Number','Partner Status','Status Description','Partner Name']]
```

Comment: can you share the results of `list(df)`? most likely you have an extra whitespace in the name of the field

Comment: You should include a minimal example of the DataFrame ([`df.head(?)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html)) - [mcve].

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: I figured it out, it was a spacing issue, thanks for the suggestions and assistance